# How to replace a file in jar with command line in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jar

I have a jar, and I need to replace a class in it, at this moment, I can only open it with "archive manager" and then drag and drop the new compiled class into the jar, but I think this is really boring, if I can do with with just a command ?

Thanks ~

Comment: +1 for gui being boring :), but you should correct "archive manager"...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
zip -u stuff.jar file.txt
```

will update file.txt in stuff.zip .   Note that for `-u` file.txt must already exist in the zip file, and will only be overwritten if it's newer than the one in the jar.

Comment: great tip.  you could probably do it with 7-zip also.

Comment: Is there a solution if zip and jar are not available? I have only tar and gzip available

Answer (score 20):

what about this one

```
jar -uf YOURJAR.jar FILE
```

if the jar have a folder structure, you can keep that too

```
jar -uf YOURJAR.jar DIR/DIR/FILE
```

Look this one for more information
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html